# How to put a -Folder- and all sub contents using cURL Rest API in windows command line

Tags: rest, curl, cmd

I am able to put a file by the following command via cmd in windows:

C:>curl -v --user testName:testPW --data-binary @test.txt -X PUT myServer

The above command will add test.txt to the server, but how can I put an entire folder at one time along with all it's sub contents?

Thanks!

Comment: What has this to do with CMD.EXE. This is a curl specific question. Just because you type it at a cmd prompt does not make it a question about CMD. NOTE: You did not tag it CPU even though it will require one. YOU ARE WASTING people's money. It cost a small amount to read a totally irrelevent post in the CMD FORUM.

Comment: Wow, someone is having a bad day today... or at least I hope you don't write responses like this daily.  There are many different implementations of cURL across many different languages.  If I left cmd out of the picture, someone could suggest an answer that won't work for a cmd implementation.  That said, if you and others feel very strongly about the subject I can remove the tag if needed.